# jsmooth java wrapper windows 7 os.name is not correct

Tags: java

I want to warp my java application by using jsmooth   tool.
I am working on windows 7 PC ,and once I run my application from eclipse the following command:

```
System.getProperty("os.name")  the result is windows 7
```

But the issue that after I warp my application with exe file and run it I get that the result is :

```
System.getProperty("os.name")  the result is windows XP
```

Is there some configuration that I should do in jsmooth   tool. Like define the os.name?
Why the exe wrapper is not working fine like the java.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The problem related to the windows 7 theme and the secuirty admin of the exe file , 
1-rigth click on the exe file.
2-select the compatibilty tab
3-uncheck the box of the "run this program in ..... mode for"
4-click on apply